why values are removed from object after button click?
I am using below package for my demo application.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mui-react-hook-form-plus
Above package have dependency of react-hook-form
Object key are removed after button click don't know why ?
I am setting the value  like this on button click.
const update = () => {
    const data = {
      person: { firstName: "", lastName: "", sex: "Male" },
    };

    setValues(data);
  };

here is my component
export default function App() {
  const defaultValues = {
    person: { firstName: "", lastName: "", sex: "" },
  };

  const methods = useHookForm<any>({
    defaultValues,
  });

  const { registerState, handleSubmit, getValues, setValues } = methods;
  console.log(getValues());
  const onSubmit = (data: any) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(getValues(), null, 2));
  };
  const update = () => {
    const data = {
      person: { firstName: "", lastName: "", sex: "Male" },
    };

    setValues(data);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <HookFormProvider {...methods}>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
            <HookTextField
              {...registerState("person.firstName")}
              textFieldProps={{ label: "First Name" }}
            />
            <HookTextField
              {...registerState("person.lastName")}
              textFieldProps={{ label: "Last Name" }}
            />
          </Stack>
          <button onClick={update}>set value</button>
          <br />
          {JSON.stringify(getValues("person"), null, 2)}
          <br />
        </form>
      </HookFormProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-61ya5m?file=src%2Findex.css,src%2FApp.css&terminal=dev
steps to repr

Run application .. see OBJECT Value { "firstName": "", "lastName": "", "sex": "" }
Click Button see Object { "sex": "Male" }
firstName. and lastName key removed from object why ?


i say internally removing field why
https://github.com/adiathasan/mui-react-hook-form-plus/blob/master/src/utils/form-utils.ts

@TusharShahi sorry ///... updated the question

The button is missing the type attribute so it has type="submit" by default. When you click the button you are calling update and submitting the form at the same time. The update function overwrites the form state and doesn't include the fields with falsey values it seems.
Simply omit the onClick={update} handler from the submit button. I recommend also being explicit about the button type.
If you have the need for an additional button that does not submit or update the form, i.e. it just needs to access the current form field values, then use the getValues utility.
const defaultValues = {
  person: { firstName: '', lastName: '', sex: '' },
};

function App() {
  const methods = useHookForm<any>({
    defaultValues,
  });

  const { registerState, handleSubmit, getValues, setValues } = methods;

  const onSubmit = (data: any) => {
    // Data is the current updated form field values

    console.log("submit", data);
  };

  const handleEvent = () => {
    const data = getValues(); // <-- access current values

    console.log({ data });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <HookFormProvider {...methods}>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
            <HookTextField
              {...registerState('person.firstName')}
              textFieldProps={{ label: 'First Name' }}
            />
            <HookTextField
              {...registerState('person.lastName')}
              textFieldProps={{ label: 'Last Name' }}
            />
          </Stack>
          <button type="submit"> // <-- submit type button
            set value
          </button>
          <button
            type="button" // <-- non-submit button
            onClick={handleEvent}
          >
            Event
          </button>
          <br />
          {JSON.stringify(getValues('person'), null, 2)}
          <br />
        </form>
      </HookFormProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

If you are trying to manually update the form state then it seems you can include the person key in the setValues utility.
Source Code
Example:
setValues(data, ["person"]);

The utility doesn't do a deep merge, so you can either manually shallow copy all the form field state you want to update, or you can flatten your form state.
Example:
const defaultValues = {
  firstName: '', lastName: '', sex: '',
};

function App() {
  const methods = useHookForm<any>({
    defaultValues,
  });

  const { registerState, handleSubmit, getValues, setValues } = methods;
  console.log(getValues());
  const onSubmit = (data: any) => {
    console.log('submit', JSON.stringify(getValues(), null, 2), data);
  };

  const update = () => {
    const data = {
       firstName: "", lastName: "", sex: "Male",
    };

    setValues(data); // <-- includes all root keys
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <HookFormProvider {...methods}>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
              <HookTextField
                {...registerState('firstName')}
                textFieldProps={{ label: 'First Name' }}
              />
              <HookTextField
                {...registerState('lastName')}
                textFieldProps={{ label: 'Last Name' }}
              />
            </Stack>
            <button
              type="submit"
              onClick={update}
            >
              Submit
            </button>
            <br />
            {JSON.stringify(getValues(), null, 2)}
            <br />
          </form>
        </HookFormProvider>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}


I want to update SEX property  using setValues ..see updated link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-61ya5m?file=src%2Findex.css,src%2FApp.css,src%2FApp.tsx&terminal=dev

I added submit and set value button ...still keys are removed ///

my main concern is when updated any keys it remove NULL and BLANK values key .. don't know why

@user5711656 They don't appear to be removed as far as I can tell. I'm not very familiar with stackblitz, let me know if this link works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-7e6gxm?file=src%2Findex.css,src%2FApp.tsx&terminal=dev. Enter some values in the fields and submit the form.

Thanks for reply ...I don't want form values . Let me explain you again...my issue is when I run application I have two IMPUT  field and TWO BUTTON in my form . I don't want to do anything . when I click on first button I want to use SETVALUES function .. it should update the form values ..  I don't want to click submit button

Expected output after set Value button click is. {   person: { firstName: '', lastName: '', sex: 'Male' }, }

@user5711656 What are you trying to accomplish here? When you edit the fields the form data is already updated.... there's no need to use a separate button to do this manually, the form is already up-to-date. What is the point of the extra non-submit button? If you just need the current values then use getValues.

it's a just event .. may be I can use SETTIMEOUT and update the form values ..

@user5711656 I've updated answer with a bit more explanation and suggestion to get the behavior you describe wanting. Please check it when you have availability.

You don't need to call an update method via onClick.
it should be a submit button. handleSubmit does all the works for you.
function App() {
  const defaultValues = {
    person: { firstName: '', lastName: '', sex: '' },
  };

  const methods = useHookForm<any>({
    defaultValues,
  });

  const { registerState, handleSubmit, getValues, setValues } = methods;
  console.log(getValues());
  const onSubmit = (data: any) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(getValues(), null, 2));
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <HookFormProvider {...methods}>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
              <HookTextField
                {...registerState('person.firstName')}
                textFieldProps={{ label: 'First Name' }}
              />
              <HookTextField
                {...registerState('person.lastName')}
                textFieldProps={{ label: 'Last Name' }}
              />
            </Stack>
            <button>set value</button>
            <br />
            {JSON.stringify(getValues('person'), null, 2)}
            <br />
          </form>
        </HookFormProvider>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

Demo
Clarify.
 <button>set value</button>

By doing this, it says button's default behaviour called submit.
So it will trigger the handleSubmit via onSubmit.
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>

if you still want to have the update button.
  const update = () => {
    setValues({...getValues(), sex: 'Male'});
  };


how to update ???

You don't need to call setValues via update method separately unless you do it for specific reason. Look at the answer. The button i have removed the button onClick so it's now set as submit button.

bro I need that button to update form values..see updated code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-61ya5m?file=src%2Findex.css,src%2FApp.css,src%2FApp.tsx&terminal=dev

I have added a new update function. Check at the bottom of my answer
